# Django rest framework browsable API not working

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-1.10

I went through DRF documentation for setting up Browsable API  but it says to implement this:

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls
```

But i am getting module `include_docs_urls` not found

I want to achieve API documentation for function based views using django 1.10.5 & python 3.5.&
Django rest framework 3.5.4

Can anyone please help me to solve this ?

Thanks alot

Comment: url(r'^docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title')) did you include url in urls.py?

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed

when i try to import this method it gives me "module doesnt exist error"
How else do i auto generate API docs ?

Thanks

Comment: wait i am looking ... seems mentioned version doesnt have documentation module

Comment: confused with your question. are trying for browsable api or DRF documentaion?

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed i have a set of APIs written in Django function based views.
I want to be able to auto generate API docs for these using DRF or someother tool.